# How do I get rid of eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm already at the limit of 9 and most of them are 5km eggs. Is there any way to get rid of them? I want to make space for 10km eggs because I hope they contain rarer Pokémon.

[image: Lots of short eggs]

Answer (score 37):

There doesn't seem to be a way to remove eggs as of this moment. Seems like the only way is to hatch them.

Source: Multiple mentions of it on Reddit.

Comment: I hoped I've overseen a button on the interface, thanks for telling me. Guess that means it's time for a walk in the park. :)

Comment: @Gigala Yeah, I've tried to fiddle with options and eggs but there is no way that you can do anything but put them in an incubator, there's also no way to get it out of an incubator.

Comment: for now i put all the 2km eggs in the infinite incubator and only 5 or 10 km in the ones that cost something

Comment: If you have a ceiling fan, apparently tying your phone to it makes it "walk" a lot....

Comment: As of 2020 April, you have to hatch those eggs to create extra space. Pushing people to walk to empty the slots. And i think they will never allow to delete eggs because it hurts :D

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed impossible to get rid of your eggs other than hatching them. Although your theority about the distance needed for the eggs to hatch and the likelyhood of a rare pokemon has been confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

As of this update, there is no clear way to get rid of eggs.

The best and only way to get rid of eggs is to hatch them, you have you walk to hatch them. You have to hatch them to get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to discard eggs. I think it's part of the game and it's way of limiting things. You must walk to catch Pokémon, so just don't forget to have some incubating. Just got a CP 722 Electabuzz from a 10km egg!

Answer (score -3):

The ability to delete Eggs has still not been introduced to the app, however this is certainly a feature that Niantic will be forced to implement in the near future.

If you want this feature and hope to contribute to the cause, click on the 'Pokéball' while in-game, followed by the 'Settings' button to 'Report High-Priority Issue'.

Comment: I don't think that is what the report button is intended to be used for.

Comment: @Dragonrage Not like they read the reports anyways..

Comment: That's not true either @Insane , considering how popular the game is, the amount of reports coming in per day is too much to respond and handle. - Overall, Dragon is still right, Best leave the report feature for bugs and issues, The Devs have other channels for low priority feature requests.

Comment: @NBN-Alex Yeah obviously they're swamped, which is why it's pointless to even use the feature, no matter how positive oriented you may be. Oh I'm sure they'll get to it!

Comment: That doesnt sound like a good idea at all and will most likely only cause niantic more work